# Inserting multiple users in Google Identity Platform - Nodejs / React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I have been using Firebase auth for handling my sign up / sign in process. But my team is changing to using Google Indentity Platform (to benefit from the OIDC / SAML), so I'm confused in this change :

1. The sign in / sign on process is handled in the front end (using React) for both Firebase and Identity Platform so we are using Fireabase sdk in the react app. But there are some function that needs to use the admin SDK in the backend that we were handling it with NodeJS admin sdk, for example (admin.auth().getUserByEmail etc..) .. but we didn't find the auth key configuration for the identity platform to use it to configure the admin SDK (if we can use the firebase admin sdk in identity platform).
2. I have a list (+100) of (emails , passwords) that I must create accounts in our Identity paltform, but the issue is the sign up is being handled in the front-end and our goal is to write a code in the backend (prefered in the backend) to extract that list form file and create accounts using a loop one by one (because we will use each identity paltform ID created in some other logic).

So my questions are :

The registration of a new account is done in the frontend (react) .. can I do it in the backend ? because I have a list that requires a loop to create an account one by one

Comment: I'm unclear as to what your question is here.

Comment: Please recheck the questions

Comment: Please limit yourself to one question per post. Posts with multiple questions could get closed as off-topic.

Comment: Hi, I edited and left only one question

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) to create user accounts programmatically.  There is detailed documentation available for [creating user accounts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user).

Comment: Hi, where to find the config key for the admin to use it with Google Identity Platform ?

Comment: If you have a new question, please post it separately along with your code.  I suggest starting with the documentation for the Admin SDK that I linked to.  The first link has everything you need to get started.